Vite is trying to read svelte.config.js even thought Svelte settings are inside vite.config.js
Vite (or one of its plugins) is trying to read a svelte.config.js file that I've never used, even though my Svelte configuration is inside vite.config.js.
❯ bun dev
$ vite --host
Error reading svelte.config.js

  VITE v5.3.3  ready in 603 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://192.168.68.102:5173/
  ➜  press h + enter to show help

vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'
import autoImport from 'sveltekit-autoimport'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    autoImport({
      components: [
        {name: './src/components/containers', flat: true},
        {name: './src/components/displays', flat: true},
        {name: './src/components/files', flat: true},
        {name: './src/components/inputs', flat: true},
        {name: './src/views', flat: true},
        './src/components',
      ],
      module: {
        'svelte-apollo': ['mutation'],
        'svelte/transition': ['fly', 'fade'],
        svelte: ['onMount', 'setContext', 'getContext', 'createEventDispatcher']
      },
    }),
    svelte({
      onwarn(warning, defaultHandler) {
        if (warning.code.startsWith('a11y-')) return;
        // handle all other warnings normally
        defaultHandler(warning)
      }
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      lib: path.resolve('./src/lib'),
      store: path.resolve('./src/store'),
      queries: path.resolve('./src/queries')
    }
  },
  base: './'
})


Notice that configFile: false is not working as expected:
https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/main/docs/config.md
If I create a svelte.config.js with an empty export default I get rid of the Vite error:
export default {

}


All my packages are updated. I don't need the above empty file, however, I don't know why I get that error if I remove it, don't know how to avoid Vite to look for it. Any help will be really appreciated.

It seems to be linked to sveltekit-autoimport, if I remove it from your config the warning disappear.     I try this fix: https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/main/docs/config.md#disable-automatic-handling-of-svelte-config but it does not seem to change anything

The problem seems indeed to be here: https://github.com/yuanchuan/sveltekit-autoimport/blob/a0cfc5089630c6f10e0cb45ee460552970e476c9/src/index.js#L100

thank you so much Axnyff, direct to the line, I'm gonna reported it or use an alternative!
